# Get max and min values of a colum using mysql information_schema tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table with millions of records in mysql and it is difficult to query that table and get min and max value for a particular column. It takes lot of time to output.

Is there a way to get those values using mysql information_schema tables. Please help.

Comment: Millions should not be a problem you would be better examining the indexes to see if they are appropriate.

Comment: You can have a look at this post, it can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102279/mysql-min-and-max-of-each-column

Comment: It is almost 20 crore records and is there a way to get those info from information_schema tables?

Comment: Wassa crore? and No it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get minimum / maximum values through `information_schema` for any columns. `information_schema` contains **metadata** only that describe the database structure. It does not contain any information on the actual data stored within the darabase structure.

You need to look at your indexes and their use in your aggregate queries to speed up the counts.